# VB.net add line break to string in Excel

Tags: vb.net

I have a string that I want to write to Excel

Example of the string is:

```
Dim excelString As String = "this is my string <br /> this is my second string"
```

I want to write that string to Excel but with line breaks, so the result will be

[image]

How can i achieve this? I tried replacing `<br />` with `vbLf` but Excel just process it as a string. I can't manually alter the Excelfile as this is an automated process.

Comment: You might need to provide some code examples for how you are reading/writing to the Excel file now.  Are you using a NuGet package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I splitted the string on `<br />` and added it to a stringbuilder.

```
 Private Function Split(tosplit As String)
            Dim myDelims As String() = New String() {"<br />"}
            Dim splitted As List(Of String) = tosplit.Split(myDelims, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList()
            Dim stb As New Text.StringBuilder()
            For Each item In splitted
                If Not item.Equals("") Then
                    stb.AppendLine(item.Trim())
                End If
            Next
            Dim returnValue As String = stb.ToString().Trim()
            Return returnValue
        End Function
```

Apperiantly when you add items to a stringbruilder it puts linebreaks that Excel understands in the string which are preserved as you convert the stringbuilder back to a string

Comment: I believe StringBuilder.AppendLine actually appends `Environment.NewLine` under the hood. I think my code and your code does the same thing in practice, only mine is more concise.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the NewLine property ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.newline)):

```vb
Dim excelString As String = "this is my string <br /> this is my second string".Replace("<br />", Environment.NewLine)
```

My guess as to why the vbLf constant is failing ([documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vblf)) is because it represents just the line feed and Excel is expecting the carriage-return and line feed.

Comment: Yeah i fixed it in a similair way. I splitted the text and appended the lines to a stringbuilder. That worked.